# Why do these "else if" statements not work?

Tags: java

I began writing the code below and wnated to test it. It only works for the if-statement not the rest of the else if-statements. If you know where the problem lies please tell me. Thank you!
Side note: I know this code is unnecessary long probably but as long as it works I figured it wouldn't matter.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class DOOMSDAY {


public static void main (String[]args){
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

int monats_code = 0;
System.out.print("What month is your date(z.B: Januar, Februar, usw.)?: ");
if (user_input.next().equals("Januar")){
    monats_code = 6;
}
else if (user_input.next().equals("Februar")){
    monats_code = 2;
}
else if (user_input.next().equals("März")){
    monats_code = 2;
}
else if (user_input.next().equals("April")){
    monats_code = 5;
}
else if (user_input.next().equals("Mai")){
    monats_code = 0;
}
else if (user_input.next().equals("Juni")){
    monats_code = 3;
}
else if (user_input.next().equals("Juli")){
    monats_code = 5;
    }
else if (user_input.next().equals("August")){
    monats_code = 1;
    }
else if (user_input.next().equals("September")){
    monats_code = 4;
    }
else if (user_input.next().equals("Oktober")){
    monats_code = 6;
    }
else if (user_input.next().equals("November")){
    monats_code = 2;
    }
else if (user_input.next().equals("Dezember")){
    monats_code = 4;
    }
else System.out.print("Seems like there is a problem!");

System.out.print(monats_code);

String tages_code ;
System.out.print(" What is the day of your date?: ");
tages_code = user_input.next();

System.out.print(tages_code);

}}
```

Comment: Don't keep calling `next()` inside of your if blocks!!! Call it once before the blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a new input token in each condition. You need to call `user_input.next()` just one time, store it in a `String` variable and use it in all conditions :

```
String input = user_input.next();
if (input.equals("Januar")){
    monats_code = 6;
}
else if (input.equals("Februar")){
   ...
} ...
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Damn guess I really embarassed me here haha.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `user_input.next()`, it requires another piece of input from the user; it doesn't just keep reusing the same value over and over.

If you want to do multiple comparisons against the same value, you need to store the result of `next` in a variable, and use that instead. Something like this:

```
String input = user_input.next();
if(input.equals("Januar")){ //...
} else if(input .equals("Februar"){//...
}//...
```